# Ошибка при установке Qt

Tags: qt5, qtcreator, установка

Постоянно при установке Qt выводит следующее:

```
 Error during installation process (qt.tools.win32_mingw530): Executing
 failed(Unexpected exit code: -1073741515):
 "C:\Qt\/Tools/QtCreator\bisdktool.exe assTC —id  ProjectExplorer.
 ToolChain.Mingw:qt.tools.win32_mingw530.gcc —name MinGW 5.3.0 32bit
 —path C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/gcc.exe —abi
 x86-windows-msys-pe-32bit —language 1 —supportedAbis
 x86-windows-msys-pe-32bit"
```

Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: От админа запускаете? Антивирус выключен?

Comment: Аналогичное наблюдал на некоторых антивирусах. Пока не удалил их, ничего не получалось - антивирус решил, что qmake - плохая программа и скопировал в отдельное место.

Comment: вот на эту строку посмотрите ` "C:\Qt\/Tools/QtCreator\bisdktool.exe assTC —id  ProjectExplorer.` там в пути `\/` так не должно быть

Comment: Ставлю на Windows 7. Такая же проблема.
Система свежая, антивируса пока нет, ставлю из под админа на чистый диск, но слэши так и скачут то в одну, то в другую сторону.<br>
Пробовал и оффлайн установщик последней версии (на текущий момент 5.9.3), и онлайн версию.<br>
Решение пока не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

У меня была похожая ошибка.
Дело в том, что последняя версия не хочет устанавливаться на XP. На Win7 всё прошло нормально.