# Точка входа в процедуру CancelIoEx не найдена в библиотеке DLL KERNEL32.dll. (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Не запускается релизная версия программы сервиса написанная на Qt на Windows xp Service pack 3. Windows установлена на Virtual box остальные программы там запускаяются, а моя нет. На Windows 10 8 7 запускается нормально, а на xp не хочет. Что может быть не так? Что можно сделать?

Comment: какой компилятор?

Comment: Qt_5_8_0_MinGW_32bit

Comment: По идее, с версии Qt 5.6 уже нет совместимости официальных бинарников с Windows XP. Поэтому придётся собирать Qt самостоятельно (ну или брать фреймворк старой версии из архива). Если всё же решите пересобирать Qt, то загляните в багрепорты ( [например](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49711) ) по этой теме. Там упоминаются ключи для сборки, которые помогут, если и не избежать проблем, то хотя бы снизить их количество.

Comment: Спс большое почитаю

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при установке Qt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629229/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-qt)

Comment: @alexis031182, предлагаю опубликовать ваш комментарий как ответ на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/629229/208074

Comment: @Arhad, спасибо. Там, как я сейчас вижу, подобный ответ уже есть, разве что без упоминания о версии. Вот только не очень понятно, действительно ли ТС ведёт речь о winxp.